# meal after late workout

Tags: workout, protein, sleep, carbohydrate

Due to my schedule I start workout at about 20:00 and finish around 22:00.
I have to get up at 7:00 so I have a dilemma of not wanting to eat much before I go to sleep and the need to eat protein and carbs after workout.

I usually have breakfast at 8:30(carbs) and lunch around 13:00(fair amount of protein) and some small amount of carbs before workout.

So I definitely need a protein meal after workout, but I just don't sleep well after that. What can I do without rescheduling my workout time?

Comment: 2 hours training is too much, the usual timespan is 45 min(without cardio) - 1 hour (with cardio). About eating - how many times a day are you eating. There should be at least 6 servings per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that important to eat after workouts, the most important factor is your total protein intake during the day.

What kind of workout do you do? If it's just weight lifting you definitely do not need carbs after workouts. An average body can store 2000 kcal of glycogen (carbs), if you are a marathon runner or professional athlete, you'll have a hard time filling that store up, but it not a problem even with a high intensity weight lifting workout.

So skip the carbs, drink a protein shake if you want to. 2 hours might be too much for optimal growth, depending on how you spend your time.

Comment: Yes, it's just weight lifting. So some protein/carb meal at around 18:00 would be good? Actual workout is about 80-90min, 2 hours including time to get back home